# PHP startup warning - sqlanywhere module

Tags: php, sybase, wamp

After a successful install of wamp server, I installed the sqlanywhere module(php-5.3.0_sqlanywhere.dll), and added it to the php.ini file as an extension.
Problem is, after startup, the Wamp server throws the following error.

> PHP Startup: sqlanywhere: Unable to
>   initialize module  Module compiled
>   with build ID=API20090626, TS,VC9  PHP
>   compiled with build ID=API20090626,
>   TS,VC6 These options need to match

Point to note is that my PHP version(5.3.0) matches the sybase module(php-5.3.0_sqlanywhere.dll)
Where might the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the module is compiled by vc9 and your PHP is compiled by vc6.

You have to match the compilers used to get it working.

More info here: http://windows.php.net/